# Firebase fetching data as Kotlin data type Any

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, any

I am trying to fetch an entire node in one shot from Firebase Real-time database as type `Any`. The code that I use is as follows:

```
val offerDetails = p0.child(querykey).child("Offers").child(offerkey).getValue(Any::class.java)
Log.d("MyMessage", 
offerDetails.toString())
```

The data is obtained perfectly as the Log returns:

```
{offer=90, ****ID=********, deliveryHour=0, mobile=******, type=2, deliveryMinute=15, offerComment=******}
```

However, I am unable to fetch the individual data like the offer, type, etc  hereon. Can someone help me out?

P.S. I can get each of the datapoints individually from Firebase. But I am trying to avoid that and instead get the entire node in one shot.

Comment: Does the data return as a Map class?

Comment: Yes. I have been able to access the data by iterating over the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
val offerDetails = p0.child(querykey).child("Offers").child(offerkey).getValue(Any::class.java)
```

The type of the object is `Any` and **no**t `Offer`, so you can access its properties. When you are using:

```
Log.d("MyMessage", offerDetails.toString())
```

You are just printing in the logcat the String representation of your `offerDetails` object. If you need to access its properties, then you should cast that object to an object of type `Offer`.

```
Log.d("MyMessage", (offerDetails as Offer).offer)
```

In this way, you are telling the compiler that the object is of type `Offer` and not `Any`. In this case, the output in the logcat will be:

```
90
```

**Edit:**

You can also access the properties using the following line of code:

```
val offer = p0.child(querykey).child("Offers").child(offerkey).child("offer").getValue(String::class.java)
Log.d("MyMessage", offer)
```

Same output (`90`) in the logcat.

Comment: Yes. I am considering casting it as an hashtag and then access the individual members. Have made some progress since posting the question.

Comment: Yes, you can do it also that way but you can also do it directly as in my updated answer. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Supported Data Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)

Your object is most likely returning as a `Map<String, Object>` object. Maybe use the map as you can read/write it better than an Any object